# ¿Cómo puedo poner una imagen de fondo en mi login?

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc

Quisiera saber como puedo poner una imagen de fondo en mi vista de login.

Quisiera que la imagen abarcara todo el fondo, porque la que viene en el código solo es un logo y esa imagen viene en una carpeta que se llama `fonts`, que es ahí donde tengo mi imagen para el fondo de mi Login, pero no se como ponerla en todo el fondo.

Este es mi codigo HTML:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}
<div class="text-center">
    <img src="~/fonts/logo2.png" />
    <h1>Farmacia Virtual</h1>
    <br />
    <h3>Iniciar Sesion</h3>
    <br />
</div>
<div class="container">
    @{
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Message))
        {
            <div class="text-center alert alert-danger">@ViewBag.Message</div>
        }
    }

        <form action="/Login/Acceso" method="post">

            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                <label>Usuario:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Usuario" name="usuario" value="" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
                <label>Contraseña:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" name="contrasena" value="" />
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" >Iniciar Sesión</button>
            </div>

        </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes crear un archivo **.css** y poner esto

```
body {
  background-image: url("logo2.png");
}
```

Luego, en el HTML debes importar el **.css** con

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nombre-del-css.css">`

Y ya estaría listo.

Comment: Si funciono, muchas gracias